# What's better in performance - clone() or instantiation with new keyword?

Tags: c#, .net

When we want to have new objects for some class, and if we already have one, should we use clone() or instantiate using new keyword?

Yes, clone() will have all the members copied as well, but I am curious for a case when this won't matter.

```
ClassType foo = new ClassType();
ClassType bar = new ClassType();  // here, will foo.clone() be better choice?
```

I need this in one of my current task as I am working with generic lists (List`<`T`>`), which get huge at times and are passed through a 'n' tiers before actually being used for UI.(they in between get converted to Array and back to list as well for serialization purpose). So, I was just thinking to better the performance.

Comment: It's not clear, are you cloning an IList<T>? or some plain C# type?

Comment: I am not cloning generic list, I am adding my own objects in the list. That's what is the center of my question.

Comment: And do you want a shallow or deep clone? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are doing premature optimisation. Profile, and you will usually be surprised where the time is going. I doubt it will be here, unless your "clone" is using serialization.

That said; `ICloneable.Clone()` is worth avoiding simply because it is poorly defined (deep vs shallow) and rarely supported. Behind the scenes, most `Clone()` implementations either just do a `new(); // now copy properties`, or they use serialization.

Comment: It would be better to hear that you had seen the source code of IClonable.Clone() or Object.MemberwiseClone() methods to claim it. A shallow copy does not imply calling class constructor, cause the new instance created not throw "new" keyword. It just copies part of memory dump(value type properties, bit-by-bit copy) into memory and copies references(reference type properties) for the new instance. And a deep copy maybe does not interesting us within the context of the question, but it implements the same but all references should be reinitialized. Сorrect me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 7):

`Clone()` will do a `new` anyhow, so why bother?

Calling `Clone()` will result in a new reference anyway and on top of that all members are copied, so it will definitely be slower.

Answer (score 4):

`clone` must allocate a new object (i.e., it calls `new` somewhere), so it can't possibly perform better.  In other words, `new` perforamance is a lower bound for `clone` performance.

Answer (score 4):

Cloning is intended to produce an object identical (more or less - i.e. deep vs shallow - i.e. a minefield) to the original, a different purpose from new which merely instantiates an unrelated class instance.

Summary: They serve different purposes, they aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

.clone is definitely slower.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine new, because clone will have to still new up the object in the background, plus the regular clone duties.

And as always, if in doubt, profile!

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on how much work gets done in the constructor. Clone() would copy every member value from the first class to the second. Does your constructor do more, or less work than that? The answer to that should tell you.